# How do store sensitive data in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I am not really used to PHP but I have to put up a quick function in PHP. I am using an email that gives an access to an API. The email has to be included in all the API calls. The email is stored encrypted in the database. How to best store and use this email address? Currently I am thinking of this.

```
getEmail
{
    //Retrieve value from DB
    //decrypt using openssl_decrypt
    return decrypted value
}

function1
{
   $email = getEmail();
   API call 1
}

function2
{
   $email = getEmail();
   API call 2
}
```

The thing I am concerned with this design is I have to do retrieval and decryption many times ( will get worse as more functions are added ). My question is how fast is openssl_decrypt ? Can my concerns for the number of calls be safely ignored? or storing the email in _Session safe? Any other methods ? Please help me. I have to make the design fast and also secure.

Comment: As far as I know, storing info in the `$_SESSION` array would be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Don't even start thinking about encryption before you've identified what threat you're trying to mitigate against.

There's no one-size-fits-all answer, it's a trade-off between how secure you have to be and how much inconvenience/expense you can endure.

Making symmetric encryption worthwhile requires rock-solid key storage. As soon as your key is disclosed to an attacker, the data can be considered compromised.

At the most extreme, keys are kept on custom crypto hardware to control access. Slightly less secure is to store the key on removable media and copy it directly into memory during boot.

At the other end of the spectrum, you can store the key on the HDD of the box doing the en/decrypting. The latter provides no real security as any server compromise would likely result in a data compromise. The only benefit is preventing users who can only access the Db from seeing the data.

If you can clarify exactly who/what you're trying to protect against, we might be able to give a more targeted answer.

One possible alternative assuming you can split read/write would be to use Asymmetric encryption instead. This way, you can prevent the server from being able to read the data it has written.

- Generate an RSA public/private key pair
- Give the webserver access to the public key only
- To add a new record, the webserver encrypts the data using the public key `*`
- To read records, the back-end process decrypts the data using the private key and sends emails/etc as appropriate `*`

This has the benefit that compromising the web server doesn't leak details about email addresses already in the system, however, it does require that any code which needs to read data must be isolated from the webserver.

`*` This is a very complex process to do correctly. Depending on exactly what you need to guarantee about the data, you will need to do at least some of:

- Hash the data
- Generate a cryptographically random key
- Encrypt the data symmetrically
- Generate a signature
- Encrypt the symmetric key using the public key
- (Store/Retrieve the message, keys, initialization vectors, etc)
- Decrypt the symmetric key using the private key
- Decrypt the data
- Verify the signature
- (More)

Note that asymmetric encryption gets expensive *very* quickly as message length increases. For this reason, it's common to encrypt the data symmetrically, then share the key asymmetrically. That way, the message size is constant and appropriate key sizes can be chosen.

Any mistakes with the above will likely risk exposure of your data. If you care about security, **do *NOT* attempt this on your own**. Find a good library that does it all for you. Pick something that's been around a long time and has been audited multiple times. That way there's a reasonable chance it's secure.